# Creating a package directly inside a project folder

Tags: eclipse

Back a few days ago I was using Eclipse Indigo and I could successfully create a package directly inside my project folder, but I recently changed my version to Juno and when I create a package it creates a normal folder instead. It will create a package if I put it inside a source folder, but the source folder is completely unnecessary. Is there a way to create a package directly inside a project folder in Juno?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the choosen value for option "Project layout" in the wizard for creation of a Java project. In your Indigo installation you had choosen the first option, in Juno you used the second option.

[image]

You can still change that afterwards on Project Properties -> Build Path -> Source.